# Spring MultiPart MediaType Unsupported

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I'm actualy trying to upload a file on my Spring server. The fact is that I always have a 415 (Unsupported Media Type) error without any error in server's log.

There is my code :

Client side :

```
  journal.import= function(id, file, callbackSuccess, callbackError){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(config.API_URL +"/newspapper/import/"+id, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        }).success(callbackSuccess).error(callbackError);
    }
```

Server side :

```
@POST
@Path("/import/{id}")
@Override
public void importJournalTypeConcurrent(@PathParam("id") long id,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
}
```

To solve this problem, I've also add a MultipartResolver

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver getMultipartResolver() {
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}
```

It's probably something stupid, but I can't find what I missed.

Comment: This might be helpful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743649/spring-multipart-mediatype-unsupported

Comment: @pa1 Wrong link I guess ;)

Comment: Oops my bad.. Hopefully This is right link ;).. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461594/set-content-type-to-utf-8-with-angularjs-http

Comment: Why are you sending the request with a `Content-Type` of `undefined`?

Comment: Because in angularJs, this type of content permit him to find it auto. Then it return : `Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryy62lavqSWBMg8cjB`

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of [MultipartResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html):

> To define an implementation, create a bean with the id
>   "multipartResolver" in a DispatcherServlet's application context

Declare the `CommonsMultipartResolver` as below:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser but with or without name, I have the same issue.

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are using Spring MVC ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Spring MVC