# Spring Web Reactive Framework Multipart File Issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, reactive, project-reactor

I'm trying to implement and image upload using Spring's Reactive Framework by trying the following:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/images")
public class ImageController {

    @Autowired
    private IImageService imageService;

    @PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Mono<ImageEntity> saveImage(@RequestBody Mono<FilePart> part) throws Exception{
         return part.flatMap(file -> imageService.saveImage(file));
    }
}
```

But I keep getting a 415 with the following error message:

```
Response status 415 with reason "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--0b227e57d1a5ca41' not supported\
```

Not sure what the issue is, I'm curling the API the following way:

```
 curl -v -F "file=@jinyang.gif" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" localhost:8080/images
```

I've tried different variations of headers and files with the same results. Kind of at a loss here because I've done this in the past and things seemed to work okay. I saw from this post that this feature was merged:

[How to enable Spring Reactive Web MVC to handle Multipart-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066619/how-to-enable-spring-reactive-web-mvc-to-handle-multipart-file)

Comment: Issue is more on the line Tomcat vs Netty. For above to work use Netty.

Comment: This was on Netty, and the underlying server didn't make the difference, see below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging around I was able to find this test in the Spring WebFlux project:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/MultipartIntegrationTests.java

So the part I was missing was `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestBody` in the controller definition.

Final code looks something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/images")
public class ImageController {

    @Autowired
    private IImageService imageService;

    @PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    Mono<ImageEntity> saveImage(@RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> part) throws Exception{
         return part.flatMap(file -> imageService.saveImage(file));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually the following solution seems to work with Netty

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/test/{path}",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, 
            produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    Mono<String> commandMultipart(
        @PathVariable("path") String path,
        @RequestPart("jsonDto") Mono<JsonDto> jsonDto,
        @RequestPart(value = "file",required = false) Mono<FilePart> file) {
        JsonDto dto = jsonDto.block();
     }
```

*Build.gradle*

```
 compile group: 'org.synchronoss.cloud', name: 'nio-multipart-parser', version: '1.1.0'

 compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.3'
 compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.3'
```

*curl* command in bash

```
echo '{"test":"1"}' > command.json && curl -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -X POST http://localhost:8082/test/examplepath/ -F "command=@./command.json;type=application/json" -F "file=@test.bin" -vv
```

**Troubleshooting steps**

1. Ensure nio-multipart-parser is present by checking method
   `org.springframework.http.codec.support.ServerDefaultCodecsImpl#extendTypedReaders`
2. You can check that nio-multipart-parser is used by placing breakpoint inside

   - `org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader#canRead()` for single part
   - `org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageReader#canRead` for multipart

   One of the above methods should return **true**.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the solution is to update the Spring version greater than 2.1.1, after this you should check that in the dependencies that are not 'spring-webmvc' since this generates a conflict with 'spring-boot-starter-webflux'