# Spring Webflux 415 with MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I am currently trying to upload a file from an Angular 4 front-end to a Spring Webflux controller. The controller is able to read the @RequestPart value but throws a 415 UnsupportedMediaTypeStatusException.

**UploadController**

```
@PostMapping( consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )
public Mono<Void> save(@RequestPart("file")MultipartFile file) {
    log.info("Storing a new file. Recieved by Controller");
    this.storageService.store(file);
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

The log.info() method does not execute so it seems that the error is being thrown before the method is executed.

**Error message**

```
org.springframework.web.server.UnsupportedMediaTypeStatusException: Response status 415 with reason "Content type 'image/png' not supported"
at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.readBody(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:206) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.readBody(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:124) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.lambda$resolveArgument$0(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:99) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:450) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:450) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:450) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:391) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:633) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFlattenIterable.java:238) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:450) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:450) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replayFused(FluxReplay.java:865) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replay(FluxReplay.java:895) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.ReplayProcessor.onNext(ReplayProcessor.java:436) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.drainLoop(MonoProcessor.java:504) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onNext(MonoProcessor.java:347) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:450) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:450) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:450) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1069) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onComplete(FluxOnAssembly.java:460) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BaseSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:404) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:712) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:666) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.drainLoop(FluxCreate.java:221) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader$FluxSinkAdapterListener.onAllPartsFinished(SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader.java:215) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
at org.synchronoss.cloud.nio.multipart.NioMultipartParser.allPartsRead(NioMultipartParser.java:603) ~[nio-multipart-parser-1.1.0.jar:na]
at org.synchronoss.cloud.nio.multipart.NioMultipartParser.write(NioMultipartParser.java:449) ~[nio-multipart-parser-1.1.0.jar:na]
at org.synchronoss.cloud.nio.multipart.NioMultipartParser.write(NioMultipartParser.java:370) ~[nio-multipart-parser-1.1.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader$SynchronossPartGenerator.lambda$accept$0(SynchronossPartHttpMessageReader.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
```

The dependency Spring Webflux should use org.synchronoss.cloud.nio.multipart is loaded so I am not fully understanding why the 415 error is being thrown by Spring.

I created a test using the WebClient in Spring

**WebTest**

```
    @Test
public void sendValidFileSaveCorrectly() {
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("foo", "foo.txt",
            MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, "Hello World".getBytes());
    MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
    builder.part("file", file);

    webClient.post()
            .uri("/api/file")
            .syncBody(builder.build())
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful();
}
```

I got a new 500 error instead using the MockMultipartFile and this message

```
I/O failure: org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile["inputStream"])
```

What I am trying to understand is why Spring is throwing an Unsupported Media Type exception and how I can direct Spring Webflux to ignore whatever is writing that response.

**Update**

Tried changing the controller to use @RequestParams and @RequestBody and got the same 415 error. The Multipart request is being handled but the Content-Type of the attached file is what is doing the 415.

I went ahead and added a ExceptionHandler to the Controller to try and catch the UnsupportedMediaTypeStatusException. I am not able to pass through the file to the ExceptionHandler though so this did not work. I could Override the default ExceptionHandler for the UnsupportedMediaTypeStatusException but I would prefer to avoid this if possible.

If it is useful I am posting my Angular service that is uploading the file. However because the error occurs even in tests I don't think there is a problem with the Angular.

**upload.service.ts**

```
post(file: File, fileName: string) {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, fileName);

let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.delete('Content-Type');

this.http
  .post(this.API_URL, formData, { headers: headers, reportProgress: true })
  .subscribe();
```

}

Comment: Maybe try @RequestParam? Not sure of your use case, but maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38156711/8160553

Comment: Went ahead and gave that an attempt as well as with @ RequestBody just to try an still was getting the 415. I am going to try and do a @ ControllerAdvice to catch the CodecException and see if I can just manually save it through that

Comment: For better visibility, I would edit the post to add the methods you've already attempted.

Comment: Looks like you have to use @RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> part instead of @RequestPart("file")MultipartFile file please refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703924/spring-web-reactive-framework-multipart-file-issue. If this works, let me know I will write down the answer to claim the bounty ;-)

Comment: Look like duplicate:

Comment: Look like duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066619/how-to-enable-spring-reactive-web-mvc-to-handle-multipart-file.
All that you need update spring version.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi using Flux<FilePart> was the way I did it and that ended up working completely. A little annoyed the documentation said MultipartFile would work

Comment: @GrigorievNick I have a more updated version of Spring than mentioned in the link you posted

Comment: @FattySalami so the issue resolved now, does it mean you can close this thread?

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi yes I wanted to give you a chance to post an answer but I can close the thread

Comment: I will post the answer, thank you

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Please use the `@RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> file` or `@RequestPart("file") Flux<FilePart>` instead of `@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file`.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Mono<Void> save(@RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> file) {
        log.info("Storing a new file. Received by Controller");
        this.storageService.store(file);
        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

Comment: I have done the same thing in one of my project where i use reactive spring.
But i'm unable to test it, how can i call the API through Swagger or postman.
Swagger doesnt show upload file button.  When i use postmen it changes the content type depending on the file we upload, whiich will throw unsupported content type agaian

Comment: You might want to refer below link on how to test the multipart example with a file in postman. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022213/2453985

Comment: Just ran into this, thank you! But why is that? Is this documented behaviour? A 415 seems like a bug for me, there could be at least a more descriptive exception of what's happening...

Answer (score 2):

You must use Flux or Mono as type for multipart upload.
https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/multipart/src/main/java/com/example/demo/MultipartController.java